# Problems keeping CxxTest GUI open

Tags: c++, bash, unit-testing, testing, cxxtest

I am trying to run some test cases using CxxTests directly in the terminal and with the GUI enabled. According to [documentation](https://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD2387/kurskatalog/cxxtest/docs/guide.html#TOC34),

> The default behavior of the GUI is to close the window after the last test.

by default, the GUI closes when the CxxTest execution ends. In my case, I want to keep the GUI open after the execution ends, I see that the official documentation explains how to do it in the section [3.5.2 Leaving the GUI open](https://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD2387/kurskatalog/cxxtest/docs/guide.html#TOC36),

> The Win32 GUI accepts the -keep which instructs it to leave the window open after the tests are done. This allows you to see how many tests failed and how much time it took.

however, I don't really understand where I have to put that `-keep` flag.

This are the instruction I use to run CxxTest, any idea where the `-keep` fits in?

```
>>> cxxtestgen -o tests.cpp myTestSuite.h --gui=Win32Gui
>>> g++ -o tests tests.cpp
>>> ./tests
```